# MySQL: Cannot add foreign key constraint error in school project

Tags: mysql, key

I'm building a really basic database for a school project and am getting a "cannot add foreign key constraint" error in MySQL. I've been scratching my head on this one for the past day, read all of the related posts and haven't been able to figure it out.

Here are the first two tables of my project:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
CUST_ID      INTEGER    NOT NULL     AUTO_INCREMENT     UNIQUE,
CUST_LNAME      VARCHAR(25)    NOT NULL,
CUST_FNAME      VARCHAR(25)    NOT NULL,
CUST_INITIAL   CHAR(1),
CUST_STREET_NO   VARCHAR(6),
CUST_STREET_NAME     VARCHAR(25),
CUST_APT_NO     VARCHAR(10),
CUST_CITY     VARCHAR(25),
CUST_STATE     CHAR(2),
CUST_ZIP_CODE     CHAR(5),
CUST_HOME_AC     CHAR(3),
CUST_HOME_PHONE     CHAR(8),
PRIMARY KEY (CUST_ID))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE INVOICE (
INVOICE_ID     INTEGER    NOT NULL   AUTO_INCREMENT   UNIQUE,
CUST_ID      INTEGER    NOT NULL,
INV_DATE   DATE    NOT NULL,
SPECIAL_HANDLING   VARCHAR(35),
PRIMARY KEY (INVOICE_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (CUST_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I'm sure it's something super easy that I'm missing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the column to be referred in your foreign key constraint def.

Use:

```
FOREIGN KEY (CUST_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUST_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

instead of

```
FOREIGN KEY (CUST_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

So, `create table` becomes:

```
CREATE TABLE INVOICE (
INVOICE_ID     INTEGER    NOT NULL   AUTO_INCREMENT   UNIQUE,
CUST_ID      INTEGER    NOT NULL,
INV_DATE   DATE    NOT NULL,
SPECIAL_HANDLING   VARCHAR(35),
PRIMARY KEY (INVOICE_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (CUST_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUST_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to declare the name of the foreign key, and then declare the column of the current table and the table and the reference column

CONSTRAINT fk_customer FOREIGN KEY (INVOICE_ID)
  REFERENCES customer(CUST_ID)